# Creating a Azure Oracle Database and Import Database dump file placed in BLOB storage into Oracle Instance in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to resolve below problems:

- 1) Take Database dump from a Oracle Database(On Prem)
- 2) Create a Oracle Database in Azure
- 3) Place the On Prem Database dump file on BLOB storage and import the database in the Azure Oracle Database.

For creating database dump, i am trying to use SQL Developer Database Export utility. But struggling with the output format.

For Azure Oracle DB, i have deployed Oracle Standard 12.2 from MarketPlace, but don't know how to create a DB and import DB using BLOB storage DUMP file

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/).

It supports [Oracle Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle) connector and [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) connector.

Here is an official detailed [guide](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-onprem-oracle-connector.md) about transferring data from or to Oracle DB on-prem.